# Cannot index file with unicode chars in solr

Tags: solr

I am doing the official solr tutorial, and when I try to index a json file (provided by solr) where one of the json objects contains `"name": "\u00bfQui\u00e9n es el se\u00f1or L\u00f3pez?"` I get the following error

```
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 (Bad Request) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/films/update/json/docs
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: {
  "responseHeader":{
    "rf":2,
    "status":400,
    "QTime":25},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","java.lang.NumberFormatException"],
    "msg":"ERROR: [doc=/en/quien_es_el_senor_lopez] Error adding field 'name'='¿Quién es el señor López?' msg=For input string: \"¿Quién es el señor López?\"",
    "code":400}}
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/films/update/json/docs
```

I get errors as well for the xml and csv versions of the same file, again provided by solr. In those files the movie name is stored without any encoding ("¿Quién es el señor López?").

Edit: I found out that the issue was actually my curl commands before the indexing were all returning 400. For example: `curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{"add-field": {"name":"name", "type":"text_general", "multiValued":false, "stored":true}}' http://localhost:8983/solr/films/schema` returns

```
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
curl: (3) Port number ended with 't'
curl: (3) Port number ended with 'f'
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 12
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":0},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"no stream",
    "code":400}}
```

Comment: check if the server where solr is hosted has the utf-8 encodeing

Comment: if you have the utf-8 enabled then try using ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory for your field

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti I found that actually the issue was my curl commands before indexing were all returning 400. I edited my question.

Comment: try and have in one line as below curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{ "add-field": { "name":"name",  "type":"text_general",  "multiValued":false, "stored":true} }'http://localhost:8983/solr/films/schema

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti The issue was that I am on windows, and I need to use all double quotes and escape the inner ones. Thank you though!